# where to put to have a method for relationship for has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Project
  has_many :pages
end

class Page
  belongs_to :project
end


@project = Project.first
@project.pages.list_out
```

where should i put to have a method list_out for pages?

Comment: Failing to understand the question. What's `@project.pages.list_out` supposed to do exactly? Also, "where should I put to have X?" means about nothing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Project
  has_many :pages

  scope :list_out, joins(:pages).where('pages.project_id = ?', self.id)
end

class Page
  belongs_to :project
end

@project = Project.first
@project.list_out
```

Comment: I prefer to use methods, not scopes nowaday

Answer (score 1):

```
class Project
  has_many :pages

  def list_out
    pages.map(&:id)
  end
end

class Page
  belongs_to :project
end

@project = Project.first
@project.list_out
```